# problem navigating from app to baseview model with this base ctor

Tags: mvvmcross

I have a base class on **baseviewmodel**.

I'm facing navigationservice implemented on 6.2 on debug shows problem navigating to another viewmodel.

debug shows userdialogs break.

Is there a problem using base class in this way with those parameters . anyone faced this kind of issue

```
        public BaseViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService, 
                             ILoginService loginService,
                             UserDialogs userDialogs, IValidator validator) {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _loginService = loginService;
            _userDialogs = userDialogs;
            _validator = validator;
            Title = TextSource.GetText(StringResourceKeys.Title);
            IsBusyMessage = Resources.Strings.LoadingMesssage;
        }
```

using gettext provider like this

public class ResourcexTextProvider : IMvxTextProvider
    {
        private readonly ResourceManager _resourceManager;

```
    public ResourcexTextProvider(ResourceManager resourceManager)
    {
        _resourceManager = resourceManager;
        CurrentLanguage = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    }

    public CultureInfo CurrentLanguage { get; set; }

    public string GetText(string namespaceKey, string typeKey, string name)
    {
        string resolvedKey = name;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeKey))
        {
            resolvedKey = $"{typeKey}.{resolvedKey}";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceKey))
        {
            resolvedKey = $"{namespaceKey}.{resolvedKey}";
        }

        return _resourceManager.GetString(resolvedKey, CurrentLanguage);
    }

    public string GetText(string namespaceKey, string typeKey, string name, params object[] formatArgs)
    {
        string baseText = GetText(namespaceKey, typeKey, name);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseText))
        {
            return baseText;
        }

        return string.Format(baseText, formatArgs);
    }

    public bool TryGetText(out string textValue, string namespaceKey, string typeKey, string name)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool TryGetText(out string textValue, string namespaceKey, string typeKey, string name, params object[] formatArgs)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to inject `UserDialogs userDialogs` in the ctor of your `BaseViewModel`. My guess is that you missed registering the userDialogs.

First of all you should inject interfaces instead of implementations to improve maintainability:

```
Mvx.IocConstruct.RegisterType<IUserDialogs, UserDialogs>();
```

And if my guess is correct and you are using `Acr.UserDialogs` you should [initialize it](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs#android-initialization-in-your-main-activity) and [register it](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs#mvvmcross) as:

```
Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IUserDialogs>(() => UserDialogs.Instance);
```

Then you can inject it in any `ViewModel` directly using the interface:

```
public BaseViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService, 
                     ILoginService loginService,
                     IUserDialogs userDialogs, 
                     IValidator validator) {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _loginService = loginService;
        _userDialogs = userDialogs;
        _validator = validator;
        Title = TextSource.GetText(StringResourceKeys.Title);
        IsBusyMessage = Resources.Strings.LoadingMesssage;
    }
```

HIH

Comment: You are the best

Comment: do i need register all that i inject what how to register ImvxNavigationService (type, singelton or ConstructAndRegisterSingleton) which one is ifor ImvxNavigationService?

Comment: `IMvxNavigationService` is already registered by the Mvx framework. If you want to override that register with your own implementation of `IMvxNavigationService` you do that as Singleton or ConstructAndRegisterSingleton by overriding in your `Setup` the method `InitializeNavigationService` as you can see here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Core/MvxSetup.cs#L354